# How to remove packed.js and packed.css from richfaces

Tags: eclipse, maven, richfaces, packed

I have a problem that I cannot seem to solve. I have been handed a large project and asked to reduce the size of certain pages to speed up loading times for mobile users however the project is a lot more complex then I am used to and I am kind of drowning. 
It is a JSF project using Maven with Eclipse and my problem is as follows, everytime I put the projects war file into Jboss and run it it downloads 2 files called packed.js and packed.css which account for nearly 70% of the page size. I have removed all other unwanted files but I do not know how to remove these, I am pretty certain that packed.js and .css are not being used but I do not know how to prevent these from loading or how to even find where they are being loaded. The only thing I could find in relation to it was that Richfaces is what is loading them. I cannot find anything else about it

The following lines of code are from the top of each page being used.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
template="/templates/my-template.xhtml">

    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
```

I believe it is one of those that is causing this to happen, I removed the rich faces reference however that broke the project, I am sorry if there is a well known solution but I do not know how to remove those files. If there is any other code snippets needed just let me know which ones. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: packed.css and packed.js make RichFaces work, you don't want to get rid of those

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was wondering because there is multiple builds to this project and one of the builds has richfaces but not the packed.js and packed.css files.

Comment: That build has likely turned off resource optimization, it makes the server load the resources in separate files. If you are only using a few RF components it might help (because it will load only the resources you need) but otherwise it's better just to load the single file that contains everything.